# Need to add javascript to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have not added any javascript files except for the ones created by the scaffolds.  IN the applications.html.erb file, there is a line that was pre generated:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Heroku does not like this. When I comment out this line, I can use my app but some of the routing is messed up.  I was able to get around some of the routing problems by adding GET routes to the links that were giving me trouble.  I am still having a problem with all the links that go to destroying something... like when I hit a destroy link (i.e. the one generated by the scaffold), it sends me to the show view for the thing I wanna delete.

Is there a way to fix this while leaving javascript commented out or do I have to do something to get javascript working?  Also to note, this is my first RoR application.

Comment: what version of rails are you running?  What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: I am running rails 3.1 I believe.  It says something like "application error". it was a vague error.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't altered any settings i application.rb rails 3.1 will run with asset_pipeline.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, in this guide you can read how rails combines script and minifies them.

When pushing to heroku (which also assumes asset pipeline if not altered) you probably not run

```
rake asset:precompile
```

and the commit the compiled assets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it to use another stack. There is a beta stack for Rails 3.1 called Cedar.

You can use the Bamboo stack but not with the asset pipeline. You can change your stack too Cedar.

For more information: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar